# Cannot set starting offset for spark-eventhubs

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-iot-hub, spark-structured-streaming

We are using **Structured Spark Streaming** together with the package **spark-eventhubs** to read messages from the Azure IoTHub. In some situations, Spark checkpointing does not work as we want. Therefore, we would like to be able to set the starting offsets manually.

Our plan was to assign the offsets manually in the IoThub Parameters Map, by either setting:

- `"eventhubs.filter.offset" -> {"partitionKey1":"Offset1", ...}` or
- `"eventhubs.startingOffsets" -> {"partitionKey1":"Offset1", ...}`

Both versions didn't work, meaning that Spark always starts reading from the earliest message obtained from the IoTHub.

Also we are not sure if the syntax above is ok, since there is no documentation on this.

We use Spark 2.1 and the spark-eventhubs package from Maven:

```
"com.microsoft.azure" % "spark-streaming-eventhubs_2.11" % "2.1.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently inherited this library a couple weeks ago. In the current version (2.1.5), there is no support for per partition configuration and there is a lot of documentation missing.

The next release will support per partition configuration of starting offsets (or enqueue times) and max rates. There will be quite a few more improvements as well. Additionally, new documentation on configuring the library and using it with Structured Streaming, Spark Streaming, and Spark Core will be posted. I'll post a detailed road map on GitHub soon.

Sorry for the trouble and thanks a bunch for you're interest. I'm trying to whip the library into shape, so if you have more feedback/questions I'm happy to chat here or on GitHub!